# Graph with uneven spacing in excel

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2008

I need to make a graph of follow-up data at 0, 6, 12, and 24 months.  Excel for Mac 2008 puts the 24 months at the 18 month position.  How do I get the correct spacing without including 18 months?

Answer (score 1):

Use an “X Y (Scatter)” chart, like this:

[image: Sample with “X Y (Scatter)” chart with X values of 0, 6, 12, and 24]